# Route Actions to same URL

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'd like to hide requests for several controllers 'create' action in a common url. The controllers all are in a sub-folder in the Controllers directory:

```
Controllers \ mydirectory \ controller1
                          \ controller2
```

I've tried it this way

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "controller1Create",
    url: "buy",
    defaults: new { controller = "controller1", action = "Create" }
);
```

and have changed controller1 to

```
 ../mydirectory/controller1
 /controller1
```

But anytime I go to the create action, the url remains the same ..   .com/controller1/create

**How to do that right? Thank you for your help!**

Comment: Obvious question: You have, of course, placed your custom route **above** the default route in RouteConfig.cs, right? Because if your custom route comes **after** the default route, the default is the one that'll be executed, and will result in the url such as what you have stated in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your input, yes, the custom routes were placed above the default route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, creating a folder for these controllers won't actually do what you want. ASP.NET MVC doesn't care about where your controllers are, it will scan the assembly and all controllers will behave like they are in the root.

If you put a controller named Controller1 in Controllers/MyDirectory. It will still be reachable from `/Controller1`  URL and `MyDirectory/Controller1` will fail.

What you need is an area. You have to create an area for these controllers put them inside its own Controllers folder.

Then you can use an area route like this in AreaRegistration class:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "MyArea_default",
        "MyDirectory/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Create", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```